# jquery text function - how to pass on the current value of the selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery

***HTML:***

```
<tr class="headrow">
    <th colspan="3"><span id="bigspan">-</span> Main Header </th>
</tr>
```

***JQuery:***

```
$('tr.headrow').click(function () {
    // Find the span inside the headrow and toggle its value to '+'
   $(this).find('span').text(<<HOW?>>);
});


<<HOW?>>>
```

Now I need to add something into the jQuery text function by which I can toggle the text val of the selected element (here it is span). I basically want to change it '+', if its current val is '-' and vice verse

Comment: The element has an `id` so you could select by that, however given your structure it seems like you may have duplicate ids when they should be unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to toggle the text

```js
$('tr.headrow').click(function() {
  // Find the span inside the headrow and toggle its value to '+'
  $(this).find('span').text(function(i, t) {
    return t.trim() == '-' ? '+' : '-';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="headrow">
    <th colspan="3"><span id="bigspan">-</span> Main Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="headrow">
    <th colspan="3"><span id="bigspan1">-</span> Main Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="headrow">
    <th colspan="3"><span id="bigspan2">-</span> Main Header</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer contains duplicate (triplicate?) ids! Our eyes hurt :)

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg I just copied the same row 3 times :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function with `html` to modify the contents, based on the contents:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vwtmwz0a/2/

```
$('tr.headrow').click(function () {
    // Find the span inside the headrow and toggle its value to '+'
    $(this).find('span').html(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).html()) == '-' ? '+' : '-';
    });
});
```

*`text()` is just as good in this instance. I use `html()` out of habit :)*

Comment: This is Exactly same as Arun P's ans.

Comment: @Query Angry Bird: They are only *similar*. We were obviously both working on it at the same time.

Comment: Nothing , you will too get +1

Comment: @Query Angry Bird: Makes the effort all worth while :)

Comment: Why switch from OP's use of `text()` in favor of `.html()`, when the former is at least as suitable in this case?

Comment: @Peter Herdenborg: Out of habit I tend to use `html()` in code *to allow for elements being changed later*. `text `is equally good.

Comment: I see, good point. Could just be worth mentioning that in OP's particular case, there is no reason not to use `text()`, in case he wonders why you replaced it.